# Request in application controller returns nil when testing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I use

```
request.subdomain
```

in my application controller. In develepment mode it works, but when I test it it returns

```
undefined method `subdomain' for nil:NilClass
```

I have this test.

```
describe ApplicationController do
controller do
  def index
    render text: "hello"
  end   
    end
let(:firm){FactoryGirl.create(:firm, subdomain: "test")}
let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user, firm: firm)}
describe "current" do
  before(:each) do 
    @request.host = "#{firm.subdomain}.example.com"
      sign_in(user) 
      get :index, subdomain: "test"
  end
  it "should current_firm" do
     ApplicationController.new.current_firm.subdomain.should == "test"
  end
    end
end
```

This is the method in the application controller

```
def current_firm
   @current_firm ||= Firm.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
end
```

Why is the request method nil during this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
it "should current_firm" do
   @request.host = "#{firm.subdomain}.example.com"
   sign_in(user) 
   get :index, subdomain: "test"
   assigns(:current_firm).subdomain.should == "test"
end
```

Comment: request object will be intialized only during a http request. Calling ApplicationController.new.current_firm is not a http request

Comment: thanks! That fixed it. Ran into a new problem. I have a method in the application controller that I can pass arguments to. Like this `ftz(time)`. How can I do that using `assigns`?

Comment: assigns is used for instance variables(@current_firm). not methods.

Comment: I can help you if you can explain a bit more about your scenario and related code